# Est-il possible d'éviter quelqu'un ? Ou on n'évite que quelque chose?

Tags: sens, expressions, complément-cod

I'm writing a French directed writing, and I'm trying to express the idea that I avoided a disagreeable person.

The sentence I'm struggling to form currently is

> Malgré cela, la situation n'était jamais trop grave, car je **l**'ai
> **évité**. (je n'ai pas parlé avec lui ; je n'ai presque jamais parlé avec
> lui ; je me suis caché de lui)

Est-il possible de dire *éviter quelqu'un* ou ferais-je mieux d'employer une construction différente ?

Comment: The text of your question does not correspond to the title ; try to make your request precise. You can use the edit command  under your text (Share Edit Follow Close Flag) so as to modify your sentences (or the title).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oui, on peut éviter quelqu'un ou quelque chose. Antidote : Faire en sorte de ne pas subir. _Éviter une situation fâcheuse. Éviter de justesse un conflit. Éviter les responsabilités. Éviter un coup. Éviter un accident. Éviter le regard de quelqu’un._ Faire en sorte de ne pas rencontrer (quelqu’un, quelque chose). _Éviter la personne à qui on doit de l’argent. Éviter les trous, les serpents, un indésirable._ À mon avis, la question de Joseph est suffisamment claire. Mais je modifierais votre phrase.

Comment: Malgré cela, la situation n'a jamais été grave puisque j'ai réussi à l'éviter à plusieurs reprises.

Comment: What is French directed writing?

Comment: Il faudrait préciser : _puisque j'ai réussi à éviter X_.

Comment: @Oreste merci bien pour tout ce que vous m'avez dit. Ça m'aidera beaucoup avec mon examen de français

Comment: @Lambie Every Mod Lang taught in Scotland at Higher level (between AS and A level in England, below Bac level in France) is assessed on three papers and one discussion. The writing exam is called, "directed writing" because you are given a scenario and the examiner requires you to discuss 6 points relating to that scenario. It's easy if you don't get told you're off to a concert/festival, or the French are coming to Scotland. If you're at a festival, there's nothing to talk about - if they come here everything is in the passive, or you're constantly using, 'nous'

Comment: @Joseph I understand. Thank you.  éviter is like avoid, a person or a thing.

Comment: Joseph, j'ai modifié votre question pour qu'elle puisse être ouverte et j'ai voté pour la réouverture.

Comment: *Malgré tout/cependant/toutefois, la situation n'a jamais été préoccupante car j'ai pris soin de l'éviter au maximum.*